# Can a 3rd party app access other apps' notifications?

Tags: ios, notifications, ancs

I do understand that Apple emphasizes security but I have to ask: is there any way that a 3rd party app can access all notification data? Like the `NotificationListenerService` available in the Android API?

I did come across [ANCS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html), but I guess that's only accessible to BLE devices. Please tell me I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Apple does not provide access to the Notifications of other apps, nor does it provide access to any listener service, or notification queue.

Here is a link to the Apple doc, which describes the provisioning that is required to set up and access APNS: [APNS Provisioning and Development](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1)